# What exactly happened to Virgil?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, the-best-offer

In the movie [The Best Offer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Best_Offer), it is shown at the end that Virgil has been conned and his whole collection has been stolen. He discovers this after coming home from the London auction; in the next scene it is shown that he is in a psychiatric institution.

But in the corresponding scenes, he is wandering Prague (I think in the faintest hope that he might get to see Claire once again, and that her love may not have been faked completely), looking at clocks, and spinning in a wheel-like thing.

What exactly is meant by this? Is this all in his imagination, and/or does it take place after he is released from the institution? Or is it a metaphor for something else entirely?

I may have missed some important detail, but I'm at a complete loss to understand this ending part of the movie.

Comment: Similar question was asked before, check this once http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13829/what-is-the-sequence-of-events-during-the-denouement